# Nginx: How to reverse proxy each port to another specific ports?

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to configure an Nginx server to reverse proxy port 80 to port 5000 and port 8888 to port 9999.
The `server_name` is the same for both proxies.

I tried to use the following configuration but failed:

```
server {

    server_name domain.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }

    listen 80;
}

server {

    server_name domain.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/;
    }

    listen 8888;
}
```

Nginx fails to load with the above configuration.
What do I do wrong? Is it actually possible to achieve?

Comment: Please be more specific about the "fails" part. What are you doing and what error are you encountering?

Comment: @Gerald, I get `nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8081 failed (98: Address already in use)`

Comment: That seems to have no relation to the configuration you posted. Check the rest of your configuration for multiple `listen` directives to that port.

Comment: try `nginx -T|grep 8081` and also `losf -i :8081`

Comment: Do you have something else running on port 8081? Check with netstat -tulpn